# Mori cone of Picard rank two varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-geometry, divisors, minimal-model-program

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety of Picard rank two. Assume that there exists a surface $S\subset X$ such that
$$i^{*}:\text{Pic}(X)\rightarrow\text{Pic}(S)$$
is an isomorphism, where $i:S\hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion. Furthermore, assume that there is a curve $C\subset S$ such that $h^0(S,aC) = 1$ for all $a\geq 0$. Then $C$ generates an extremal ray of the Mori cone of $S$. Does $C$ generate an extremal ray of the Mori cone $\overline{\text{NE}}(X)$ of $X$ as well or might it lie in the interior of $\overline{\text{NE}}(X)$?

Comment: The condition in the displayed formula seems to be unfinished.

Comment: You are right. I corrected my question.